# Convert PDF URL to base64 format or download the pdf format from IFrame in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to convert to base64 format from URL but it turns out to be invalid when i try to convert that base 64 to PDF document online (Via some tool).
Similarly i tried to use the same url in IFrame tag and was able to view it but is there any way i can download that same file from Iframe.

Code i tried to convert URL to base64 - It converts but it turns to be an invalid set of characters.

```
const content = window.btoa(props.offerLetterURL);
```

I was able to view from the same url from iframe so is there any way i can download the same from iframe

```
 <iframe
        src={URL}
        title="Download File"
        id="hiddenDownloader"
        width="88%"
        height="65%"
      ></iframe>
```

Thank You,